# Change variable url after checking value of radio buttons in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I got this form.
They added a radio button selection. Now I would like the url behind the submit button to change depending on which radio button is selected. So every choice gets his own url and so it's own page. (this is needed for analytics)
I am not very well know with php but it seems there is a way but can't get it to work.

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/trial-email.php" class="contact-form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="<?php echo $locale->language; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="button" value="<?php echo $_GET['button']; ?>">            
  <input id="text1" type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company name" />
  <input id="text2" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name>" />
  <input id="email1" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input id="tel1" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />

   <div class="how-find-us">
     <span class="how-title">How did you find us?</span>
     <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Online advertisement" checked>Online advertisement
     <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Google">Google
     <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="A Friend told me">A Friend told me
     <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Other">Other
   </div>

  <input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="<?php __translate('Fill in the characters'); ?>" />
  <div class="captcha_image" >
     <?php
      $_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
      echo '<img src="' . $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src'] . '" alt="CAPTCHA" />';
    ?>
   </div>

  <span class="submit-holder"><input id="submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="<?php __translate('Get trial'); ?>"/></span>
</form>
```

I tried the code below but it did not work, it even broke the page.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Online advertisement" checked>Online advertisement
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Google">Google
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="A Friend told me">A Friend told me
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Other">Other
<span class="submit-holder"><input id="submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="get trial"/></span>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{
echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

I read that it is possible to use the $_GET because that saves info in the url?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this,

```
if(isset($_POST['radio']))
{
    echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}
```

This should be `howbutton`

```
if(isset($_POST['howbutton']))
{
    echo "You have selected :".$_POST['howbutton'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
}
```

Comment: thanks! I found a similair solution. turns out I had to take a look in another file too. The trail-email.php where I added `$howbutton = $_POST['howbutton'];` and `if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
      //header('Location: thanks.php?locale='.$locale);   
        header('Location: thanks.php?locale='.$locale.'&choice='.clean_string($howbutton));`
It's a ugly solution but in this case....well long story but I can justify it.
thanks for the response.

Comment: No changes to the html/php but just in the form-file (the trail-email.php).
I made it read the value of the button that was selected and put that in the url that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `name` for your submit button, which renders your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` false. You are also trying to `echo` the data from the wrong element name, it should be `$_POST['howbutton']` Try the below code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Online advertisement" checked>Online advertisement
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Google">Google
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="A Friend told me">A Friend told me
  <input class="how-radiobutton" type="radio" name="howbutton" value="Other">Other
<span class="submit-holder"><input id="submit" name="submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="get trial"/></span>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 if(isset($_POST['howbutton'])){
    echo "You have selected :".$_POST['howbutton'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found something similar.
The trail-email.php where I added `$howbutton = $_POST['howbutton'];` and `if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)){
      //header('Location: thanks.php?locale='.$locale);   
        header('Location: thanks.php?locale='.$locale.'&choice='.clean_string($howbutton));`